# Can I negate NestJS's Guard?

Tags: typescript, passport.js, nestjs, nestjs-passport

I have `AuthGuard` from `@nestjs/passport` used on one my method (route) like this:

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@Req() req) {
    return this.userService.findOne(req.user.id);
  }
```

Can I negate this guard, so **only users without JWT can go trough**? I do not want users with JWT in header to access login/register route accidentally.

Comment: Yea! Build a new guard that will reject requests with jwt

Answer (score 1):

As bashleigh said in her comment, you can create your own guard that checks for a jwt and rejects if it comes in. A simple example could be something like

```js
@Injectable()
export class NoJwtGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const auth = req.headers['Authroization'];
    // as you should not have any authorization headers you an reject if the header exists
    return !auth;
  }
}
```

While it isn't possible to immediately negate a built in guard, you could also extend the `AuthGuard('jwt')` and then in your custom implementation of `canActivate` you could `return !super.canActivate(context)`